# Gazebo Example(Template) Code and using Gazebo API

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Can someone kindly give me some example codes using only Gazebo(without ROS) making advantage of the GAZEBO API?

I want to learn these API by examples because I really don't know how to make good use of Gazebo API and find out what I really want(any suggestions?). For example, how to apply joint force to a model using codes(NOT GAZEBO GUI)? How to place models in random places in Gazebo, etc.

I will appreciate any advice! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8201/gazebo-example(template)-code-and-using-gazebo-api/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I think it's a good way to download the gazebo source code and read it. This is a better way to learn to use GAZEBO API.

As for applying joint effort, I can use controller_manager provided by ROS and there is tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0